# Am I using these Probability Theory Terms Correctly?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Theta$ be a random variable with sample space $\{\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n\}$.

**Questions:**

1. Is it terminologically correct to refer to $\Theta$ as a "parameter"? What about the members $\theta_k$ of its sample space? Are they also "parameters"?
2. Are the "values of $\Theta$" the members of the sample space? For example, is $\theta_1$ a value of $\Theta$?

Comment: Unless $\Theta : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$, i.e. it maps the sample space onto itself, the variable doesn't take the values in the sample space

Comment: So what you're saying is that to claim that $\theta_k$ is a value of $\Theta$ makes sense only if $\theta_k$ is in the image of $\Theta$? In other words, the answer to (2) is "no, not generally, unless $\Theta$ is a function defined on itself". Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sample space is a population, each of whose members has an income, then the income of the randomly chosen member of the population is a random variable.  I.e. a random variable is a function whose domain is the sample space.

In some problems each point in the sample space may be a value of the random variable: for example, the outcome when a die is thrown is a member of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and that may be taken to be the sample space, and the randomly chosen on of those numbers is the value of the random variable.

But in other problems it's different: Suppose *two* dice are thrown, and the *sum* of the two resulting number is the random variable you're calling $\Theta$.  Then there is a sample space with $36$ members: the pairs.  But a value of the random variable is not one of the pairs; it is the sum.  Notice that $(1,3)$, $(2,2)$, and $(3,1)$ are different points in the sample space, but all three yield the same value of the random variable, which is $4$.  In that case, if $\theta_1$ is one of the $36$ pairs, then $\theta_1$ is not one of the values of the random variable, but $\theta_1$ is a member of the sample space.

Parameters, however, are something else.  Let's say we paint $N$ of the $3$ marbles in an urn red and the other $3-N$ green.  You will choose one marble at random from the urn.  Let $X$ be the number of *red* marbles so chosen; thus $X$ must be either $0$ or $1$.  In that case:

- $N$ is a **parameter**;
- The sample space is the set of three marbles in the urn;
- The random variable is $X$, which must be $0$ or $1$;

In this case, the members of the sample space are not values of the random variable.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I'm unfortunately still confused, for it seems people flip back and forth in how they use these terms. For example, you speak of $X$ being a random variable "which must be $0$ or $1$". But I thought that saying $X$ was a random variable immediately implies it is a *function* whose *value* is either $0$ or $1$. 

Isn't this the case?

Comment: A second question: when we say that $N$ is a **parameter**, does that imply it is a function or an element (in this case, a natural number that is inside the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$)? Are all parameters themselves random variables?

Comment: @PP121 : That is one of the ways in which confusion between a function and one of its values often happens in informal speech.  And that actually makes me suspect that our ways of making these things precise are not perfect.  Parameters are not generally random variables, and in this case you'll notice that I have not specified any probability distribution, e.g. $\Pr(N=3)=\text{what??}$, etc.  But in some cases assigning a probability distribution to a parameter and treating it as a random variable is just what is done.

Comment: "Are all parameters themselves random variables?"  No.  But _some_ are.

Comment: So, just to clarify: a random variable *is* a function; however, we will sometimes informally refer to its values as if they were random variables (which is technically incorrect).  Next: parameters aren't necessarily random variables, nor do they necessarily give rise to probability functions. This is because a "parameter" is nothing but a plain old variable (in the mathematical sense: i.e., a name that denotes something).  Is this the case? If so, my confusion is gone :)

Comment: Pretty much.  But when I say the random variable $X$ must be either $0$ or $1$, I don't mean $0$ is a random variable or $1$ is a random variable.  In just mean that for each outcome in the sample space the value of $X$ must be either $0$ or $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

In my classes in probability, $\Theta$ usually denotes the parameter space, i.e. all values a parameter can possibly take, but it might differ. For instance, for a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the parameter space $\Theta = (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_+)$.

Comment: That, however, is a matter of notation.  In the question as phrased, $\Theta$ is a random variable that can take any of $n$ values, and the question was whether _that_ set or its members are parameters.  And the answer to that is "no". ${}\qquad{}$